# Printed python variable does not equal variable value

Tags: python-3.x, pdb

I have a python script which calls a php function using subprocess. The output of the php script is captured as a variable for further use. When analysing the stored variable I have found that if I print the variable it has a different value than the variable itself and I can't understand why. I am bracing myself to be embarrassed so please enlighten me.

Yes the password in this fictional example is "password"

```
cmd = "/usr/bin/php -f /opt/hello_world.php {} {}".format(encrypted_password,of_secret)
decrypted_password = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
print(decrypted_password)
pdb.set_trace()
```

in pdb here is the output

```
password
(Pdb) decrypted_password
'\x00p\x00a\x00s\x00s\x00w\x00o\x00r\x00d'
(Pdb) print(decrypted_password)
password
(Pdb) locals()
{'cmd': '/usr/bin/php -f /opt/hello_world.php f2e57ba074b3c3d8d4d010bcff13083dc5928107f8cfbfaa4a52fff0155eebe5 JqiRnKJBaSwEOCI', 'decrypted_password': '\x00p\x00a\x00s\x00s\x00w\x00o\x00r\x00d'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.get_output()` is returning a byte string, but Python is recognizing it as a string. So you need to first `.encode()` that and then `decode()` it:

```
>>> '\x00p\x00a\x00s\x00s\x00w\x00o\x00r\x00d'.encode().decode('utf_16_be')
'password'
```

It is encoded in UTF-16 BE, which is giving two bytes to each character hence the `\x00` for a zero.

You may be able to adjust the locale or otherwise manipulate the encoding to recognize the string properly.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks very much. Do you happen to have any links for further reading on this? I feel I need to review this further as clearly I am lacking in my understanding this subject. Thanks again!

Comment: @PhillipStack For character encoding/decoding you could look at the Python unicode docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html   For the other fixes, it depends on your operating system, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will review. Appreciate your time.